# Does Black Butler have other OVAs or seasons?

Tags: black-butler

I have watched a lot of *Black Butler*. Other than seasons 1, 2, and 3 ---I'm not sure if there's a season 3--- and *Book of Murder* and *Book of Circus*, I can't find anything else.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have listed are the only animations with:

- Season 1 containing 24 episodes and 1 OVA
- Season 2 containing 12 episodes and 6 OVA's
- *Book of Circus* containing 10 episodes
- *Book of Murder* as 2 OVA's.

Ref: [List of *Black Butler* Episodes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Black_Butler_episodes).

Answer (score 0):

In *Black Butler*, there is season one & season two. There are also *Book of Murder*, *Book of Circus*, and *Book of Atlantis*.

Comment: Additional note: *Book of Atlantis* is an anime movie, not TV series.